# What kind of glove offers the best protection when using an angle grinder?

Tags: safety, angle-grinder, grinder

I wanted to start doing metalworking for a long time and I finally got an angle grinder of 4 1\2". I also bought the appropriate safety equipment face shield, some safety glasses and I'm planning to use a thick leather jacket that I always use in the workshop.

Though I'm very confused about the gloves, **I always intend to use both of my hands to handle the device with the guard on at all time** so I'm not worried about my gloves getting caught in the disc, what I am mainly worried about is that **the disc explodes** *and lacerates or cuts off my fingers*. I've seen that the most common gloves are leather gloves mostly goat skin but I've seen videos of people putting a glove against an angle grinder and it goes through it like it's nothing. Also also I've read that some people want to feel how the blade is behaving so that's another fact to take into consideration.

I don't know which is better a **leather MIG welding glove** or an **ANSI A9 cut resistant glove**??, **I want to keep my fingers as they are**.

Comment: The guard should protect hands since hands should be behind guard, and flying pieces hopefully will only fly in directions.  Should have about a 45 degree safety cone.  Best gloves would be ones that give solid control over grinder and trigger.

Comment: It Sounds logical

Comment: With machine tools, gloves aren't necessarily the most correct answer.  Sometimes you have more risk of the machine snagging the glove and pulling your hand into the maw, than you do from not wearing hand armor.

Comment: This is really more of an opinion question. Gloves and guards are great eye protection is mandatory but at times you find you can not do the job with a guard, and I can’t activate the safety with gloves on. So unless a glove that allows dexterity but not much cut /frag resistance or gloves that protect but reduce control of the tool. It is an opinion, I notice most of the millwrights only putting gloves on to weld also.

Comment: Be aware that the guards for a grinding disk and a cutting disk are different. The grinding disk guard covers the "top" of the disk (the side where most of the tool is) and around the edges to ensure sparks are directed away from you. The cutting disk guard also covers the "bottom" of the disk and covers about 1/2 of the disk to contain the shrapnel should the cutting disk explode (which they do). It's the very thin cutting disks that will cause significant damage. A thicker grinding disk might bruise or even cut the skin, but cutting disk shrapnel could sever a finger or embed in a leg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want moderately heavy leather (or an abrasion-resistant alternative), and you want a good fit.

Firstly, angle grinder blades aren't very dangerous. Abrasive wheels can go through leather fairly quickly, but it takes a lot of force. The vast majority of hand contact will be quick and light. You won't even notice it. I've even bumped bare skin against abrasive and diamond wheels with no real injury. If the wheel disintegrates<sup>*</sup>, the guard should take the hit.

Any halfway thick leather is fine. You don't want Isotoners, and you don't want leather so thick you can't bend or feel anything.

Just as importantly, you want a good fit. You want the glove to stay in position for a good grip, and you don't want loose material hanging where it'll get caught in the machine.

Finally, *don't wear gloves when using toothed, rotating blades*. I recently violated this long-known rule and almost paid dearly for it. My glove slipped a bit and got nicked by a 12" miter saw. Had it grabbed the glove's fabric more aggressively it could've pulled my fingers right in. Foolishness noted.

---

<sup>*</sup> *That's* where danger can be introduced. Folks don't realize how fast an angle grinder operates, and inappropriate blades can come apart, sending shrapnel outward with astonishing force. Use only approved blades and be sure they're installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Before i retired 14 years ago, I used an angle grinder many times during the work week. My answer is simple, any glove of any design and/or material is better than no glove at all. The glove you use is not supposed to provide you with 100% safety especially if you do not use common sense and a good work ethic. The glove is supposed to help protect you somewhat from when you forget that that tool can be a dangerous item and that care and concentration is always necessary. Any glove type will not protect you when you use that tool foolishly or for something that is not designed to be used for. My 2 cents.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Something like a latex glove will not offer abrasion protection and may actually snag and pull fingers into the tool.